# What counts as a binding notice of copyright in older books?

Tags: united-states, copyright

What counts as a binding notice of copyright in older books? Some just show the author or company and the date with no copyright symbol. Say if it just says the company and 1920 with no copyright symbol or notice, does this qualify as a notice of copyright in the United States?

Comment: You mean under US copyright law, or somewhere else?

Comment: Yes US copyright law mainly. But some books I have are from England.

Answer (score 1):

For United States works from that time, a copyright notice required the copyright symbol (©
or something very close to that), the original copyright holder's name, and the year of first publication.